# Conditional Search a string & concat with another field using MongoDB aggregation

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to search a set of documents on a field called `SERVICES`.
When I search, and

**IF :** I find first word or words at the beginning of string is `Mail` or `Envelopes delivered` or `Lost suitcase` or `Found mail`.

**THEN :** I add to the string `SERVICES` a period and string value of `LAGUAGES` field. `LAGUAGES` string is:  ‘Needs immediate action’.

**Sample Data:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "SERVICES" : "Mail has been packaged and sitting in mail room",
    "LAGUAGES" : "Needs immediate action"
}

/* 2 */
{   
    "SERVICES" : "Envelopes delivered to client but were not signed for by anyone",
    "LAGUAGES" : "Needs immediate action"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "SERVICES" : "There were problems with the client's luggage",
    "LAGUAGES" : "Needs immediate action"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "SERVICES" : "Lost suitcase at airport while in transit",
    "LAGUAGES" : "Needs immediate action"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "SERVICES" : "Found mail sitting at airport mailing room",
    "LAGUAGES" : "Needs immediate action"
}
```

**Required Output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "SERVICES" : "Mail has been packaged and sitting in mail room. Needs immediate action"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "SERVICES" : "Envelopes delivered to client but were not signed for by anyone. Needs immediate action"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "SERVICES" : "Lost suitcase at airport while in transit. Needs immediate action"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "SERVICES" : "Found mail sitting at airport mailing room. Needs immediate action"
}
```

**Tried below query:**

I did a `$match` first just to filter the information but seems to only filter the last `$OR` in my statement.  Need help.

```
{
  $match: {
    $or: [
      {
        SERVICES: { $regex: "Mail.* " },

        SERVICES: { $regex: "Envelopes delivered.* " },

        SERVICES: { $regex: "Lost suitcase. * " },

        SERVICES: { $regex: "Found mail. * " },
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

How do I search these strings and return the above output.  Thanks.

Comment: Try to separate conditions in different objects. like: $or: [ {service...}, {service...} ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use aggregation's [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/index.html) operator :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          SERVICES: { $regex: /^Mail/ }
        },
        {
          SERVICES: { $regex: /^Envelopes delivered/ }
        },
        {
          SERVICES: { regex: /^Lost suitcase/ }
        },
        {
          SERVICES: { $regex: /^Found mail/ }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  /** `$addFields` will re-create `SERVICES` field with new concated string value
   *   Or if you just want `SERVICES` field then use `$project` with `_id :0 ` */
  {$addFields : {SERVICES : {$concat : ['$SERVICES','.',' ','$LAGUAGES']}}}
])
```

Or you can use `$in` instead of `$or` :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { SERVICES: { $in: [/^Mail/, /^Envelopes delivered/, /^Lost suitcase/, /^Found mail/] } } } , 
  {$addFields : {SERVICES : {$concat : ['$SERVICES', '.', ' ','$LAGUAGES']}}}
]);
```

Comment: Working perfectly